# Data length of table not being reduced

Tags: mysql, mysqladministrator

We have a large InnoDB table which is gigabytes in size. We're now clearing it up. Rows are being removed however from MySQLAdministrator, the data length of the table has not reduced at all. Why is this so? Should we run "Optimize table"?

Thanks!

Krt_Malta

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL innodb not releasing disk space after deleting data rows from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944/mysql-innodb-not-releasing-disk-space-after-deleting-data-rows-from-table)

Comment: You can also check this question/answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/230551/mysql-innodb-innodb-file-per-table-cons/231400#231400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `optimize table` will work.. The space made available by your deletion is not returned to disk but is most probably empty indeed. The engine will simply start using that free space before taking up more physical disk space.