# About autoextend functionality in innodb of mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a server with limited storage

```
/apps:    available 60GB ;   used 59GB ; free 1GB
```

We have mysql datadirectory pointed to /apps

```
datadir                   /apps/mysql/data/
/apps/mysql/data/ibdata   50GB
```

Yesterday we observed the server shutdown with table full error which is a disc full basically.
So we have purged one old month data in one of the tables and have 10GB free space under innodb. But still there only 1GB free space on the file system.

Now if I try to insert again, whether the innodb again try to auto extend the ibdata file or it used the 9GB free space?

Comment: The tablespace does not shrink unless you recreated, but it should re-use the available space within.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944/mysql-innodb-not-releasing-disk-space-after-deleting-data-rows-from-table

Comment: I have tested the same locally. It is using the free available free space.