# Move Big Table from AWS MYSQL

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a question about getting a huge table to local machine from mysql running in AWS. 
I just created a table which has a size of 2.3GB, however I have only 2 GB free disk space. 
This lead into a situation that I even can not dump my table into a dump file which would cause error 28. Then I have two choices.

1. Clean up the disk with 300+MB free space. 
   I have already tried to delete everything I could. 
   I have only 2.5G database but mysqldb1 takes up to 4GB size which I have no idea.

   ```
   ubuntu@ip-10-60-125-122:~$ df -h
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/xvda1      8.0G  5.6G  2.0G  74% /
   udev            819M   12K  819M   1% /dev
   tmpfs           331M  184K  331M   1% /run
   none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
   none            827M     0  827M   0% /run/shm
   /dev/xvdb       147G  188M  140G   1% /mnt
   ```
2. Split my table into two different tables or more which I could dump then seperately and then put them together later.

I am new to mysql and hope a safe and easy solutions could be provided.

Best regards and let me know if I could do anything to improve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that you actually don't have that much data stored in the database, you might want to take a look at this other question here on SO:

[MySQL InnoDB not releasing disk space after deleting data rows from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944/mysql-innodb-not-releasing-disk-space-after-deleting-data-rows-from-table/1280625#1280625)

By default, MySQL doesn't reduce the file sizes if you delete data.  If your MySQL is configured for per-table files, you should be able to reduce the data by optimizing the database.  Otherwise, you'll have to get all the data to another machine and recreate the database with per-table files configured.