# Google Cloud SQL wrong instance size

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Few days ago instance's size in Cloud SQL stucked. There was a lot of data (~164 GB) but two days ago database was greatly maintained and cleaned, so now it takes much less space (~10-20 GB I think). Developers Console still shows "163.9 GB of 250 GB". Don't know how to force size update. Restart did not help.

And also a strange thing with backups at "Operations" tab:
    Aug 17, 2014 7:10:07 AM Backup  Done     An unknown error occurred
On "Overview" tab the last backup in the list is from August 14. So the backups are broken.

May be, there is a hidden link between these two.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are probably unrelated.

See: [MySQL InnoDB not releasing disk space after deleting data rows from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944/mysql-innodb-not-releasing-disk-space-after-deleting-data-rows-from-table).

You will need to contact Cloud SQL support directly for the issue with your backup. Email them at `cloud-sql@google.com` and include the instance name.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. The solution is to export instance's data, remove instance, create it again and import data from saved file. Dropping tables will give no effect.

Comment: Backups are fixed by Google, now it's ok.