# Dropping a SQL database in Google Cloud

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

We are testing the Google Cloud SQL service and we have a problem when importing our database.

Imported file include this command:

```
DROP DATABASE $my_db
```

But Google Cloud SQL dashboard still shows a storage size as if nothing was deleted.

Is it the right method for deleting a database without removing the supporting VM?

I don't want to delete the whole VM as instance names seem to be reserved for two months.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944/mysql-innodb-not-releasing-disk-space-after-deleting-data-rows-from-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB will hold onto the data that it has allocated itself, so when you create a database and delete it, the storage usage remains the same. This means you can't reduce the maximum storage you have used, but InnoDB will recycle the space it has reserved if you import new data.