# Diferrence between database size in Google Cloud SQL and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have a Cloud SQL server in Google with  MySQL engine. Recently I've noticed an increase in the used storage.

That increase is inconsistent with the size of the databases.

Google says I have 1.5gb in data stored but when I calculate the size of the databases by myself I get only 200mb.

Do you know how can I check the difference? I'm using a root user to get all the information.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calculating the size?

The other thing is that InnoDB does not release disk drive space when data is deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944/mysql-innodb-not-releasing-disk-space-after-deleting-data-rows-from-table

Unfortunately for this case, Cloud SQL does not support `innodb_file_per_table`.

Comment: The problem was in the binary logs. I executed "show binary logs" and the size was about 1,3 gb.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094296/google-cloud-sql-increasing-size-until-full-disk-with-no-reason a Cloud SQL dev explains the reason for the binary log growth and how it can be purged.