# mysql table size unchanged after rows deleted

Tags: mysql

Had a table with about 2,000,000 rows (168 MB)

Deleted 1,800,000 rows but the table size is unchanged!?

Why is that? The rows where deleted about two days ago now, but the table size is still 168 MB?

MySQL 5.6.20 innodb table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL InnoDB not releasing disk space after deleting data rows from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944/mysql-innodb-not-releasing-disk-space-after-deleting-data-rows-from-table)

Comment: did you try to optimize it, to save disk operation the file is not optimize on every delete and hence the "Table" size remain unchanged.

Comment: @sumit, create an anwser :) table optimize solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to optimize it, to save disk operation the file is not optimize on every delete and hence the "Table" size remain unchanged.

You need to optimize it and sometime Re-index can also reset the table size.

Answer (score 0):

try to optimize the table because you have used delete statement. 'shrink' size of table for optimization.