# huge sql dump even after deleting large number of rows of data

Tags: centos, mysql

The size of sql dump is same(30GB) even if I delete large number of rows from mysql (myisam) table

note: this variabe is innodb_file_per_table  ON

```
mysql> delete from radacct where YEAR(acctstarttime)='2014';
Query OK, 1963534 rows affected (1 hour 30.58 sec)
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

what it the question ? 
if you have troubles with storin bakup in once.

maybe it will be esyer to transport it for you if it was smaller in size, bud more parts ?

part 1

```
select *  from radacct where YEAR(acctstarttime)='2014' and id<100000000 order by id asc;
```

part 2

```
select *  from radacct where YEAR(acctstarttime)='2014' and id<200000000 order by id asc;
```

etc ...

And after you cound compres it

PS: I cant add replay to your comment. so i will add it here:

You can view this page Vary use-full info. [MySQL InnoDB not releasing disk space after deleting data rows from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944/mysql-innodb-not-releasing-disk-space-after-deleting-data-rows-from-table)