# The size of a table does not match the records in MySQL, AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a problem with a MySQL table, the table has only 385 records that if I export them via Workbench the file is 894 KB in size. The problem is that the Data length is 10 GB when I try to inspect the table.

Note: In the table when making query only show 385 records.

The only solution to restore the size of the table that I have used is to drop the table and import it again.

I hope and you can help me to verify if it is a MySQL error or it is an attack or I don't know why the behavior is due.

The MySQL server is in an AWS RDS.

I have read the next article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.KnownIssuesAndLimitations.html

[image]

[image]

```sql
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `file` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
    `status` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=130204 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Comment: Image NOT AVAILABLE

Comment: Try to add the image which SO provides

Comment: Ready the image is in the post, waited for your comments.

Comment: As per your Image it's 13 MB and records are much more than what you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: No, in the table when making query only show 385 records.

Comment: **Data length is 10 GB when I try to inspect the table.**?

Comment: try`Analyze table table_name`

Comment: See [MySQL InnoDB not releasing disk space after deleting data rows from table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1270944)

Comment: @James you're thinking of `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.   `ANALYZE` just rebuilds the index statistics.

Comment: Yeah exactly ....  Optimize ...my bad 

Comment: I used ANALYZE TABLE and work with normality. But my question is 
how often do you recommend that you do this process with a cron.