# Is there any shell script to cleanup a huge activiti history DB without TabLock?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, delete-row, history, activiti

My activiti server DB has gotten quite big and is using a lot of disk-space. I am working with the rest API. I am trying to cleanup my DB without having a table lock, but as the DB is very large even the select query to count rows to be deleted takes half an hour. Also, can i delete all the historical data before a particular date ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL InnoDB not releasing disk space after deleting data rows from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270944/mysql-innodb-not-releasing-disk-space-after-deleting-data-rows-from-table)

Comment: "Also, can i delete all the historical data before a particular date ?". Does the table have a date/time column? If so then yes, otherwise no. Recommend not using this unless the date/time column is indexed and even then only in small batches (`DELETE FROM tbl WHERE entry_date < "YYYY-MM-DD" LIMIT 500`).